# '\n' gets ignored when creating a text file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a text file with one string (called 'summary') as the only content. summary consists of many different lines, so I use '\n' quite a lot. However, the text file that gets created writes the string in a single line. Why do the '\n's get ignored?

This is the function I'm using:

```
 function writeToTxt(summary){
  var fileType = "text/txt";
  var fileName = Date.now()+".txt";

  var blob = new Blob([summary], { type: fileType });

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = fileName;
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.dataset.downloadurl = [fileType, a.download, a.href].join(':');
  a.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
  setTimeout(function() { URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href); }, 1500);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `\n` is a line break on \*nix, but not on Windows. If you're looking at the file on Windows, that's probably why you're not seeing line breaks. For Windows it's `\r\n`.

Comment: What makes you think there are no line breaks in the file? How did you open it?

Comment: And, of course, you need to provide `\n` as part of a JavaScript string literal. Anything else (e.g. reading it from a text file) will not get it parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file creation code is fine, but `\n` isn't a line break on Windows (it is on *nix). If you're looking at the file on Windows, that's probably why you're not seeing line breaks. For Windows it's `\r\n`.

Your code works just fine for me on Windows if I use `\r\n`, and on *nix if I use just `\n`. (Many *nix tools will also handle `\r\n` line endings, what with there being so many Windows-like text files around...)

Comment: Any decent editor should show `\n` as linebreaks on Windows as well.

Comment: @Bergi: Yes. But people often seem to use Notepad instead. :-)